# Twilio multiple treads to have each call have 1 process

Tags: ruby, twilio

Using Ruby, Sinatra, and the Twilio REST API, I'm coding a customer service line for my company. When an incoming call is received, the customer is put on hold in a  `< Conference >` verb, while the application makes an outgoing call to an agent. If he accepts the call, they are then the calls bridged.

I *currently* have 3 conference rooms *(Tech Supp, Sales, and Mobile Supp)* created by my fairly linear program. But if a conference room is busy while another call comes in requesting the already occupied room, they can't reach an agent, which is problematic.

### My question is : Can I/How do I create a thread in Ruby for each incoming call so that it has its own independent process?

My reasoning behind this is : Once each call has its thread, then I can create a room called "name of department" + "@process.id".

#### ***For example : (also adding a randomly generated 7-digit number to make each conference name to make it 100% unique.***

> `@random = Random.rand(10_000_000 - 1_000_000) + 1_000_000`
>
> `puts @random`
>
> `< Dial >`
>
> `< Conference > 'Tech Supp' + PROCESS_ID \ + @random` < /Conference >
>
> `< /Dial >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Two ideas here.  Rather than getting into threads, which can get really messy, really quickly, why not just create a different conference room using the inbound callers CallSid.  I've created systems similar to what you describe before using that technique.  You system just catalogs each CallSid as it arrives so you can go back later and connect and agent to that conference.

Another option might be to use Queue.  When a new call dials in, you could just drop them in a queue (or different queues if you want) and they can wait there until an agent is ready.  The agent can then pick the next caller out of the queue to speak with.

This HowTo on using `<Queue>` might be helpful:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callqueue

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing today, using a MySQL database to store the SID seeing as its virtually unique. I had looked into the `CallQueue`, but my boss didn't want any of it, and it seemed complicated.

Comment: OK, glad you got it working.  Just for the record, <Queue> is really not  whole lot different than conference and actually kind of does what I described above for you automatically.  Its specifically for scenarios where you need callers to wait for a bit.  It has several nice features: its an FIFO ordered list, so you don't have to track that yourself, and it gives you stats like number of callers currently in the queue, how long an individual has been in the queue and the average wait time for all callers in the queue.  You can build that with <Conference>, its just more manual.